# Why do we need to define data model in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, flask, flask-mongoengine

I want to understand why do we need to define a data model like the following. What is the purpose and advantages of having this?

```
class Gender(Document):
    name = StringField(max_length=60, required=True, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I am building a flask api using MongoDb as the database.

Comment: Why are you using `flask-mongoengine`?

Comment: Because I Am planning to use flask-security for authentication and it assumes ill be using flask-mongoengine for data connections @StyvaneS.

Comment: I think you should consider to visit [mongoengine](http://mongoengine.org/) website and [flask-mongoengine](https://flask-mongoengine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Thank you, I will look into that @StyvaneS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing about MongoDB that *requires* you to do this, but it seems like you're using MongoEngine, which is essentially built around the `Document` class.

It's just a representation of MongoDB schemas in your Python code, so that you can use methods such as `.save()` as well as performing data validation, etc.

Basically, it's a way to interact with the MongoDB database in an object-oriented manner. You don't *need* to do it like this, but it's very convenient.